# How to use a static random number in a trigger

Tags: mysql

I like to use a random number in a trigger, but it has to be the same for all the updated rows and I'm not sure where to put the line of code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_us_pli AFTER UPDATE ON us_pli
    // #1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    // #2
    SET @usr=new.uid;
    UPDATE users SET my_random=@rand,us7=3 WHERE uid=@usr;
END;
```

(note: the //#1 and //#2 are only there for my question).

Now somewhere I have to create a random number

```
SET @rand=RAND();
```

The problem is, if I put it at #1 the trigger won't fire, and at #2 I get a different random number for each row. And I like them to be the same for all the rows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mysql doesn't have statement-level triggers, so #1 is not really an option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this at #2:

```
 SET @rand = IF(@rand, @rand, RAND());
```

Comment: Funny thing is, if I use it like this, the first row differs from all the rest. 
    `SET @rand = IF(@rand!="", @rand, RAND());`
does the job